# Operation of filters in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have very recently started writing in VBA having written in various other languages over the years.  I am currently having some strange issues using filters in Excel VBA and wondered if anyone could shed any light on the behaviour I am experiencing.

I would like to filter by dataset by a number of different columns, one at a time, I am doing this by copying my data set to a new sheet and sorting the data there.  For the first filter I am using:

```
Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A:T").ClearContents
Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Copy Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows)
Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Sort Key1:=Range("R1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

This works successfully.  I would now like to filter by the values in Col C INSTEAD, I repeat the above code (including the `clearcontents` command as I thought that would improve my chances of success... and just swap the `Key1` value to `C1`

For second (hopefully new filter), I used:

```
 `Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A:T").ClearContents
Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Copy Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows)

'Sort the data so ascending site numbers in column C
Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal`
```

However, my data is sorted by column C after it is first sorted by column R...

How can I wipe any previous sorts applied?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could `OrderCustom:=1` have anything to do with it? Do you mean to do a custom sort?

Comment: can you please include the extra piece of code that you copied and changed "R1" to "C1"?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have to do with the fact that you aren't qualifying your worksheets and ranges, i.e., explicitly specifying which workbook or worksheet they are in. That's something you always want to do.

I've done that below and it works for me in Excel 2010:

```
Sub test()
Dim CountLV_Rows As Long
Dim wbActive As Excel.Workbook

Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook
With wbActive
    .Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A:T").ClearContents
    CountLV_Rows = .Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Copy _
            Destination:=.Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows)
    With .Sheets("Temp Data")
        .Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Sort Key1:=.Range("R1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
                                              OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                                              DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    .Activate
    MsgBox "Sorted by R"
        .Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
                                              OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                                              DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
End With
End Sub
```